# Projector mount with 2 or 3 screws

Tags: mounting, projector

so I just brought a new projector mount but the screw spacing on it is too wide for our studs. I’m just wondering What the best way to mount this is. The mount will hold a 8kg projector btw. Thanks heaps!

[image: Projector mount]

[image: Ceiling studs]

Comment: Which end of the mount attaches to the wall? The one up in your picture? If you want to attach this to a single stud, securely attach a 1 ft to 2 ft long piece of sufficiently wide board to the stud then attach the mount to that.  The wider board could be a piece of 3/4" plywood or a 2x6, 8 or 10.

Comment: @JimStewart yes it is the top part of the mount. Is there another way to mount it? Such as two screws into the thin stud and one into the thick stud? Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: Is the picture the inside of the wall that you want to attach it to? Or is that the ceiling? Is the back side of the wall accessible? If it is, then you could put in an extra 2x4 to make a perfect mounting frame.

Comment: What is the spacing of the screws on the mount, and how wide is the joist or stud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to play this

1. Mount a 2x4 on the other side of the ceiling (attaching the 2x4 to the joists with screws) and mount the projector to that. Unsightly, but it will definitely hold without any questions. Painting the 2x4 would help make it less noticeable.
2. Screw another 2x4 or 2x6 (can't tell from your pics) into place for the second side of the mount. Drill some small pilot holes in the ceiling to tell where it needs to go.
3. Mount only 2 screws into a stud. Use toggle bolts for the drywall side. It should hold well enough.
4. Use 4 toggle bolts. 8kg is about 20lbs, and that's well within the tolerances of toggle bolts. This carries the most questions, since the drywall has to hold all the weight. It should, but it may not since it's clustered so tight around the mount. If they used 3/4" drywall it should be fine.

Comment: I do like the idea of putting another 2x4 in place but I am not that confident doing it. Do you think if I drill two holes in the mount on the middle of each side (between the two existing holes) and mount it onto one stud it would be sufficient?

Comment: Possibly. It's hard to say. Drilling into the plate might also weaken it.

Comment: Ok I probably won’t do that then. What if I put two screws into the thin stud and one into the thick stud by putting a small block of wood between the drywall and the stud to end up using three screws?

Comment: That sounds like it would work

Comment: I would want to make sure to use all 4 points to mount the base even if 1 is a toggle bolt remember projectors usually produce a fair amount of heat and there is some vibration from the fan.